# How to parse excel file into json format in rails + bigquery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-bigquery

I am trying to upload data from active admin into bigquery datasets from an excel file. I can't upload the csv directly I can only either create a comma separated file or pass json object to upload data into my datasets. Is there anyway I could achieve this ?

I have tried this for uploading :

```
require 'google/cloud/bigquery'

keyfile = 'bigtest-86xxh4bxx3.json'

creds = Google::Cloud::Bigquery::Credentials.new keyfile

bigquery = Google::Cloud::Bigquery.new(
  project_id: 'bigtest',
  credentials: creds
)

p bigquery.project_id #=> 'my-project'

dataset = bigquery.create_dataset 'my_dataset'
table = dataset.create_table 'baby_names' do |schema|
  schema.string 'name', mode: :required
  schema.string 'gender', mode: :required
  schema.integer 'count', mode: :required
end

file = File.open 'names/yob2014.txt'

table.load file, format: 'csv'
```

Comment: I might need more information to help you. Do you see an Error message when running this code? Nothing happens when the code runs? Please let us know

Comment: Also, have you tried the official docs where it's mentioned how to upload CSV files into BigQuery? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#ruby